# Discussion: How to proceed on implementing a mobile app based on Ember and Titanium?

Tags: ember.js, titanium

I want to develop a multi platform mobile app with the help of Titanium. I already have a working website, which is based on EmberJs. My goal is to reuse as much code as possible. I already had a look at [Ember Titanium](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-titanium), which provides a bridge between Titanium API and Ember Views.

There are mainly two questions that i have:

**1. Which Integration project should i use?** 
Is Ember Titanium the way to go for this approach? Are there any other recommendable integration projects out there?

**2 Which parts of my existing webapp need to be rewritten(functionality of webapp and mobile app are the same)?** Ember Apps consist of Models, Controllers, Views and the Router. Is it enough to rewrite the View Layer of my existing webapp with Ember Titanium? Likely i need to rewrite the router too, but maybe i can write a generic StateManager that can be reused by my webapp and mobile app? Or am i too ambitious on this topic?

Comment: Although I think this question was very topical, am disappointed to see it closed and would love if the community explored it a bit more, it was probably shut down because you didn't offer any specific code examples to explore a certain aspect of bridging ember and titanium. From what I've understood, it is relatively easy to bridge ember and titanium if you tweak your router a bit, keep your same models and controllers and rewrite your view/template layer to be Titanium-compatible. The part I can't come to grips with is re-designing intricate css in the titanium-js css stand-in syntax...

Comment: although I can't say I've tried it yet with an ember app. In a few weeks I'm going to spend a day each evaluating Ember + Titanium and Phonegap + Titanium to see which would be better going forward. I also saw trigger.io today that seems at first glance like a rather expensive Phonegap, but I haven't explored that in depth either. Let me know how your explorations go and if you find any golden path to blaze forward.

Comment: @JackJohnson have you completed your explorations? I'm heading down a similar path and would like to hear your experience.

Comment: @Tauren The last few weeks I have focused most on the extensive ember.js refactoring from 1.0.pre to 1.0.rc-1 and its evolving relationship with a web server, but from what I gather, it looks like ember forefathers are pushing hard to make ember.js as web-server independent as Cocoa on iOS. Right now I think the best solution is a rails or node.js server with token auth for a cloud back-end, with Phonegap providing a thin layer over a device-optimized ember app for native-style mobile devices (iPad, iPhone, smartphones, tablets). Robust ember apps should easily integrate with any native fra..

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to dig up too much info on native-style ember apps either and I hope some others can chime in and add some additional resources. What I have found:

1) Brian Pattison [(github)](https://github.com/brianpattison?tab=repositories) built a bit on top of ember-titanium in these projects: [Ember-Titanium-Submodule](https://github.com/brianpattison/ember-titanium-submodule) and [Ember-Titanium Utilities](https://github.com/brianpattison/ember-titanium-utilities) . He hasn't been actively maintaining them however, and now uses RubyMotion to write iOS-only apps.

2) Luke Melia of [Yapp](https://www.yapp.us/) said that they use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to wrap their ember app into native-style iOS apps.

3) I just saw [titanium-backbone](https://github.com/trabian/titanium-backbone) on github that looks like it's actively maintained, and would probably not be very difficult to fork and adapt for ember-specific needs.

Other than that, I haven't heard too much about approaches ember developers are taking to native-style mobile apps. I feel that after building a very large ember web-app it would seem like a crazy mis-use of time and money to completely rewrite an app in a native language (or multiple native languages) for minimal performance gains. However, I haven't found many positive experiences with ember and either Titanium or Phonegap.

I'm going to be digging into this a lot more in about a month, so hopefully some others can share their experiences before then.